# Columns with same name in query output but not allowed in SSIS query output?

Tags: ssis

In reference to my last question that was answered [here](http://tinyurl.com/o7srwnd), when I run the query in QA, it gives me the output with the same column name in two separate columns just fine.  However, when I try to create a package with the query in it, I can't create it because it gives an error saying

> Error 0xc0207015: Source - Query [1](http://tinyurl.com/o7srwnd): There is more than one data
>   source column with the name 'national_provider_id'. The data source
>   column names must be unique.

So how do I go about fixing this so it won't give me this error yet give me the results I need for the output file?

Answer (score 1):

Right so SSMS and other ad-hoc query tools aren't going to care. Your output for an SSIS data flow needs to sort of behave like a table definition. You can't have duplicate column names in a table, and you can't have them coming back in a query that SSIS will use. Same holds true for a flat file connection manager. The column names must be unique, much as the error message states.

How do you correct it? Provide an alias.  I use the `AS` syntax (Column AS AliasName) but you could also use an equals syntax (AliasName = Column)

```
SELECT
  person.primarycare_prov_name,
  primarycare_provider.national_provider_id AS PrimaryCare_national_provider_id,
  rendering_provider.description,
  rendering_provider.national_provider_id AS RenderingProvider_national_provider_id
FROM person
LEFT JOIN appointments 
  ON person.person_id=appointments.person_id
LEFT JOIN provider_mstr rendering_provider 
  ON rendering_provider.provider_id = appointment.rendering_provider_id
LEFT JOIN provider_mstr primarycare_provider 
  ON primarycare_provider.provider_id = person.primarycare_prov_id
```

Comment: Thanks, bill.  I thought I had done that before but i was trying to create the column as a variable instead.